# Mostrar parte del contenido de una lista en java

Tags: java

estoy intentando mostrar parte del contenido de una lista que tengo pero no se como hacerlo. Tengo una lista de instalaciones con 30 opciones de selección pero quiero que me aparezcan solo 3, es decir, tengo por ejemplo esta lista:
Gasolinera
Ruedas
Asientos
Cajas
Cambios
Volantes
Motores
Lunas
Tornillos
...
Y quiero que solo me aparezcan Cambios, motores y lunas

```
    try {
                if (this.getInstalacion()!=null && this.getInstalacion().length>0) {
                    selectedInst = "[";
                    for (Integer id : this.getInstalacion()) {
                        selectedInst += this.getInstallationh().get(id.toString()) + ";";
                    }
                   selectedInst = selectedInst.substring(0, selectedInst.length()-1) + "]";
                if (this.getZona()!=null && this.getZona().length>0) {
                        selectedInst += " (...)";
                    }
        }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warning("ajaxSelectedInstallations (getting installations): " + e.toString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `break` y una variable de control para saber cuando parar de recorrer el `for`.

```
if (this.getInstalacion()!=null && this.getInstalacion().length>0) {
    selectedInst = "[";
    int contador = 0; // Inicializas el contador a 0
    for (Integer id : this.getInstalacion()) {
        selectedInst += this.getInstallationh().get(id.toString()) + ";";
        contador++; // Aumentas en uno el contador
        if(contador == 3){
            break; // Rompemos el for
        }
    }
    selectedInst = selectedInst.substring(0, selectedInst.length()-1) + "]";
```